# Launching app from widget: no effect of FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT

Tags: android, android-activity, widget, flags

I just want to use my application widget as a shortcut to the app and I do not want to open a new task.
So I used the FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT flag like this:

```
        Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        configIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
        PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context, 0, configIntent, 0);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget, configPendingIntent);
```

But unfortunately, each time I click on the widget a new activity is launched.

Am I missing something?

EDIT: I also tried: FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT

Comment: If you don't want a new task then you are looking for FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, if the activity is on the backstack it will receive the intent at `onNewIntent()` and `onCreate()` will not be called.

Comment: I tried your code and there is still a new instance of the Activity...

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what I commented:

`configIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.source.myApp"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

> If it has declared its launch mode to be "multiple" (the default) and you have not set FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP in the same intent, then it will be finished and re-created; for all other launch modes or if FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP is set then this Intent will be delivered to the current instance's onNewIntent().

[API reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

Comment: I tried your code, and I still get 2 different instances of the same Activity. The widget launch the Activity with the onCreate...

Comment: Add `android:launchMode="singleTop"` at your manifest, if it does not work I will take a look at a project at home because I had to deal with a similar escenario.

Comment: I "+'ed" your answer for the kind help, and will try to have a look if singleTop has some advantages over singleInstance, because the result would be the same

Comment: I updated the answer and worked for me (Android Emulator 2.2).  In my case it was not a widget but it was a pendingIntent of a notification. If it does not work the only thing that comes to my mind is that the activity is destroyed because you have activated on Dev Settings "Inmediatelly destroy activities", and check if is still alive with the adb command `adb shell dumpsys activity` to see a list of activities running at backstack.

Comment: I  also have a notification that works fine... There is something with the widget.. I can currently accept only answers with SingleInstance, because all other stuffs are not working

Answer (score 0):

Every tag I tried failed miserably...

I had to use `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` to make the widget launch my Activity in the same state than the user left it.